# Converting Visual FoxPro Database

Tags: database, visual-foxpro

Is it possible for a visual FoxPro Database file to be converted to a FoxPro 2.6 (fpd26) database file?

If possible please tell me how.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Visual FoxPro, you can copy individual tables using the COPY TO command:

```
USE YourVFPTable
COPY TO YourFP2Table TYPE Fox2X
```

You have to do each table separately.